# Replace Text in HTML with external file

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I am looking for a way to insert text into parts of a shopify website depending on the class or ID. For example:

Our product leadtimes vary depending on the time of year, but they dont vary from product to product. By referencing a file in our assets we would have 1 file to edit to make a change sitewide.

Our policies are the same for every product, but if we have a policy change I would like to modify 1 file and see that change made sitewide.

I have tried creating a file *leadtime.js* and referencing with

```
<script type="text/javascript src="{{leadtime.js | asset_url | script_tag}}"></script>
//
var leadtime = "The lead time is 100 days";
```

and then calling to it using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(leadtime)</script>
```

but I havent been able to get that to work.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Of course not: [don't use document.write](http://pomax.github.io/1473270609919/if-you-use-use-document-write-you-suck-at-javascript). Use normal DOM functions (e.g. `defer` your change-script, and then use `.textContent=...` where relevant). Also, you don't specify `type` for scripts in HTML5 unless they're _not_ javascript, HTML 4.01 is a _long_ time ago =)

Comment: Ok I have switch up my approach. I am instead:

Referencing the external file *policy.js* within theme.liquid using:
```
    {{ 'policy.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
```
The contents of *policy.js* are as follows:
```
document.getElementByID("policy").innerHTML = "this is our policy";
```
and then I am using 
```
<li id="policy" type="disc">Our full policy can be found <a href="https://bicycleglass.com/pages/policies">here.</a></li>
```

I am still not getting the results im looking for. It seems like that is not loading the script like I intend.

Comment: I figured it out, I am instead using snippets to create separate files and referencing them using {% include 'snippetname' %}

Comment: don't use `.innerHTML` if you're setting _text_, use the infinitely safer `.textContent` property. But aside from that: nice, it sounds like you figured it out on your own with just a little more "trying things", which also sounds like you probably want to delete this question again.